# Graph Api Get Schedule takes time to reflect event from Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, outlook-calendar

I am using Microsoft graph SDK to get the event schedule of users. But it is taking more than 5 minutes to reflect any change done in the outlook calander. Is there any way to minimize this delay in reflecting event status?

P.S. it's reflecting without delay for the logged in user but for the schedules it is taking time

Comment: Not that i am aware of, but 5 minutes is on higher end. You need to understand that when you make getschedule api fetches free/busy availability information for a collection of users, distributions lists, or resources (rooms or equipment) for a specified time period. So you may want to trim down the availabilityinterval, start/endtime, schedules etc.

Comment: I just tested it out with Graph explorer it's less than 30 seconds. So you can isolate the issue test it out in Graph Explorer or POSTMAN to see still if you see the same time delay or not.